# Why is there an implicit type cast from DateTime to DateTimeOffset in Silverlight?

Tags: silverlight

Why is there an implicit type cast from DateTime to DateTimeOffset in Silverlight?

Answer (score -1):

Could you provide a specific example of this?

Without more info, I assume it's so that you can use standard operators to quickly generate the DateTimeOffset object by performing arithmetic on DateTime objects. Without a more specific example toward your question, it's hard to tell.